# Blender 2.8 Vertices dissapeared

Tags: vertex-groups

I'm currently making an airplane in Blender. Yesterday when I saved and closed Blender, the. vertices where still there. Now they are not (see screenshot). Anyone have any ideas?
When I create a new file, the vertices are there.
[image: there are no more vertices, in edit mode]

Comment: This is edge selection mode. Give a try to Ctrl+1 (vertex selection), Ctrl+2 (edge selection), Ctrl+3 (face selection).

Comment: You may accidentally hit `2` or `3` and got a different selection option.

Comment: whelp , that worked thanks! can you post it and mark. it as solved thanks1